# Best practice: How to handle type safety warnings?

Tags: java, eclipse

The following statement causes a warning in Eclipse:

```
Map<String, String> options = DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.getEclipseDefaultSettings();
```

Warning:

```
Type safety: The expression of type Map needs unchecked conversion to conform to Map<String,String>
```

What is the best practice to handle this warning? Should I add an SupressWarning("unchecked") annotation? For the whole class? Or just the method? Or should I just ignore the warning? Or how can I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Until `DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.getEclipseDefaultSettings` is properly generified, I'd consider making a generified wrapper for it, and having the annotation on the internal local variable declaration inside of it. Also include a comment explaining why the annotation is "safe".

In general, you want the scope of a `SuppressWarnings` annotation to be as small as possible, and you want to have as few of them as possible. You should also have a comment explaining your reasoning each time you use one.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to 'get rid' of it permanently is to upgrade to a Java 5 or later-only version of your API that returns a parameterized map.

The simplest thing to do to sort of 'clean it up' is wrap the method that returns a RAW type in a class of your own, perform the cast there, and suppress the unchecked warning.  This way at least it's done in a single place and you're not using `@SuppressWarnings` all over the place where it may accidentally also hide a "genuine" warning.

Answer (score 1):

I find these warnings on the *declaration* line highly annoying.  And meaningless, since, deep down inside, I know that there is type erasure and it the compiler is complaining about nothing.  So I ignore them.  However, this may not be a best practice and I'm quite interested in how others approach them.  Java 7 made some improvements, IIRC, you can now go

```
List<String> = new ArrayList<>();
```

and save some redundant typing of "String" and avoid the warning.

Note - I do pay attention to warnings that are *not* on the declaration line.

Answer (score 1):

If the method returns a raw map, the only thing you can do is to make sure (from the doc or from the code) that the Map is indeed a `Map<String, String>`, and ignore the warning. The compiler doesn't have any way to check that the returned Map is ideed a `Map<String, String>`.

You should ignore the warning at the smallest possible scope, else other unsafe code could be added without warning from the compiler.

Comment: How can you tell that it is a Map<String, String>, when due to type erasure there is no such thing?  All you can verify is that it is a Map, which would be a far different warning / error message!   p.s. this mainly applies on the declaration line - see also my answer.

Comment: From the doc or from the code, as said in the answer. For example, if the documentation says "the returned Map contains Strings as keys and values", or if the code of the method makes it clear that only Strings are used.

Comment: I haven't seen many classes where the docs say "only Strings", nor where the code actually checks the types.  Any examples you use often?  I guess we run in different circles.  I have seen classes that pre-define the generics so the user can't change them, or must extend a Foo not just any Object.

Comment: If you don't know for sure that the Map contains Strings as keys and as values, you really shouldn't assign the map to a Map<String, String>. This will lead to ClassCastExceptions when using the map. You have to know it. Doing this means: the compiler doesn't know the type of the map, but I know it.

Comment: I'm talking about at creation, when the map contains nothing.